# New User becoming frustated after being put on hold twice - need help writing my question

Tags: support

I would really like answers to my questions, but I am clueless how to ask it without people placing it on hold.

Attempt #1 (I deleted but now undeleted so you can read it):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239819/is-the-monte-hall-problem-a-ludic-fallacy

Attempt #2 (not asking anything related to ludic fallacy):
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243853/help-to-understand-the-monty-hall-problem

Please help!!!
Thanks,
James

Comment: I think you have to sit down with a friend, and keep explaining your question until the friend says, "ah! now I understand what you are asking!", and then with your friend's help write up the question in the format that the friend finally understood.

Comment: Do you really have a math-related question that you want help with?  The remark in the second post: "How is it any different than 'cheating' when a host helps you?" seems either editorial judgement or possibly a topic in moral philosophy.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to avoid things like multiple explanation points.

Comment: If I may be so bold, sending emails to the people who voted to close your question is not the way to go. There is no way this could work out for you.

Comment: "why vote to close a question without at least writing a helpful comment?" -- to get the question closed, obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the first question, at the start I had no idea what being a "[ludic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ludic) [fallacy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fallacy?s=t)" would mean. After Googling the entire term I was brought to a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludic_fallacy) which indicates that it essentially means

> the misuse of games to model real-life situations.

With this in mind, I have no idea what real-life situation the Monty Hall problem attempts to model except for the Big Deal portion of the *Let's Make a Deal* game-show, of which, in my opinion, it is a pretty faithful model. If you have something else in mind you should probably state it explicitly.

Regarding the second question, it is entirely unclear what "blatant cheating" would mean. Without a clear indication of this it is really impossible to answer the question with any certainty. All we can do is guess an interpretation of "blatant cheating" and move from there, which is not really what this site is for.

---

Reading between the lines in these two questions, it appears that you want to ask something like the following:

> Does the manner in which the knowledge that behind a specific door stands a goat is gained affect the probabilities in the Monty Hall problem?

Before just posting another question you might want to spend some time reading through answers to previous questions tagged [monty-hall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monty-hall) to see if and/or how the method of gaining this knowledge is ever specifically used.

Comment: Thank you very much Arthur for taking the time to write your Answer. Your are a gentleman and I am grateful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem of you attempts

- Attempt #1 has way too many information to the point you don't know where/what is the question.
- Attempt #2 has way too few information to allow one interpret the question
  `How is it any different than 'cheating' when a host helps you?`
  accurately. Judging from the wording of this sentence alone, it doesn't look like a mathematics question at all.

To ask a really long question, make sure

- Provide some hints in the first few sentences about what sort of question is this.
  This helps people to decide whether this question is interesting to them.
- If you need to provide a lot of background information like what you do in attempt #1.
  Make sure they are visually different from the proper part of the question.

  `Never start a question will 'background information'`!
- If you need to ask multiple related questions or need to bring up multiple related points in your post, `use paragraph breaks or bullets to group them into logical units`. This help people to recognize where your questions/points start and end.

Comment: Your points are well taken. I realized too late that my first attempt was too long. Everyone on the internet (and in real life too) has a short attention span. As to 'not math related' question - it's more about understanding the logic of the math that still confuses me. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score -9):

Monte Hall is one of the most discussed examples in all of math, so it's unlikely that anybody here, or anywhere else, has anything to say about it that hasn't already been said.